# Issue in mysql data display

Tags: mysql, html

I am storing data into database in certain fashion . for eg - using enter , spaces. and it is storing successfully in same way but when i output those stored data , it simply display in single line. It is not considering any white space or enter that i have made. I wanted to display the data in same manner.

Comment: Add your `html` code to your post.

Comment: If you want a whitspace in html you have to store it in db as <br>

Comment: Did you use `nl2br();` in your PHP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nl2br()` function in the PHP while printing the MySQL Data.

```
echo nl2br($row["column"]);
```

Or, if you need them to be displayed as exactly as how it is stored, you need to either use a `<pre>` tag or you can set the CSS of the displaying object to:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Consider a text like this:

```
I have a     big house!

And there's a line before this line!
Also I have left a                huge space!
```

The whole above text would display in a `<div>` as follows:

> I have a     big house!
>
> And there's a line before this line!
>   Also I have left a                huge space!

```css
div {white-space: pre-wrap; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif;}
```

```html
<div>
    I have a     big house!

    And there's a line before this line!
    Also I have left a                huge space!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CRLF is not taken as Line Break in HTML.

You have to use [Preformatted Text (PRE)](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/literal.html)

Example:

```
<pre>
     your data field bound variable name here
     that has 
     line feed and carriage return
     as part of it's content
</pre>
```